# Backbone Changing Class Name during {{each items}}

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I want to change the classname during an each loop; 
so that it will look like this;

```
<div class="active">
  // do somthing
</div>
<div class="static">
  //do
</div>
```

my code looks like this

```
{{#each pages}}
  <div class="active">
    //do
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

there is no identifier of the class. So the 1st one will be active, the rest of the items will be static.

Comment: as far as I know there are no indices provided by `#each` that could be checked..

Comment: Are you using Handlebars for your templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add your own helper if you want to do this inside the template. Something like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('each_with_class', function(ary, first, rest, options) {
    if(!ary || ary.length == 0)
        return options.inverse(this);

    var result  = [ ];
    var context = null;
    var cls     = { cls: first };
    for(var i = 0; i < ary.length; ++i) {
        context = _({}).extend(ary[i], cls);
        result.push(options.fn(context));
        cls.cls = rest;
    }
    return result.join('');
});
```

Then your template could say things like this:

```
{{#each_with_class pages "active" "static"}}
    <div class="{{cls}}">
        Same stuff you're doing now.
    </div>
{{/each_with_class}}
```

If you don't mind `ary[i]` getting modified along the way then you can assign directly to `ary[i].cls` instead of using `_.extend` to make a copy.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/ZMSQh/1/

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know there are no indices provided by `{{#each}}` that could be checked..

a workaround would be to store this classes in your `pages` items and then use something like

```
{{#each pages}}
  <div class="{{this.classname}}">
    //do
  </div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.. but I am trying to stay away from this structure because of the fact that the collection is coming from somewhere else, and i prefer not to manipulate it if possible..